# Magento 2 Cookie Restriction Bar - css styles not applied for different stores

Tags: magento2, cookie, theme-fallback

I am working on a Magento 2 multistore setup like this:

```
www.foo.com/uk
www.foo.com/us

bar.foo.com/uk
bar.foo.com/us

baz.foo.com/uk
baz.foo.com/us
```

I have successfully styled the cookie bar for the `www.foo.com/uk` & `www.foo.com/us` store, but when I switch to the other two it inherits the default blank theme styles instead.

Everything else works as it should, I have a subfolder for every store (bar, baz) and storeview (us, uk) and all the other theme styles are applied correctly.

`bar.foo.com` & `baz.foo.com` inherit from the `www.foo.com` theme.
I tried to add the `_cookie.less` file under the specific theme subfolder but that didn't change anything.

Any other suggestions would be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question I had to add the specific _cookie.less file under every specific store folder otherwise it won't show up and then clear the pub/static folder